# What's the word for performing a manual examination

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine yourself walking into a room, and you see a pocketwatch on the table, you pick it up, look closely at it, perhaps open it up. Maybe it's one of those see through kind, so you can see some of the gears in it. You look very closely at it.

What's the word for this?

- *Inspect* gives the implication that I'm looking for flaws. I don't want that implication.
- *Examine* seems good, but doesn't give the hands-on feel I'm looking for.

Is there a word for something like this?

Comment: I think I'd say, 'He walked into the room and, moving immediately to the watch, picked it up and began to examine it closely.'  I think *examine* does carry some connotation of hands-on whereas something like *scrutinize* doesn't.

Comment: I don't think there's anything that really clearly specifies "hands-on".

Comment: Unfortunately, it's hard to even think about this topic without the mind drifting to other meanings of the term.

Comment: Maybe sth. from the [_handle_](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=H5046900) entry from the _AMHDotEL_?

Answer (score 1):

In medical circles, the verb "to **palpate**" describes a close, manual inspection of a body part.

Answer (score 0):

I think  [appraise](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/appraise) may suggest the meaning you are referring to:

> - To estimate the quality, amount, size, and other features of; judge.

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com